# Injeção de Dependência em Controller Base

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, injeção-de-dependência

Bom estou aprendendo a trabalhar com a injeção de dependências agora e gostaria de aplica-lá no meu projeto. Porém me deparei com a seguinte dificuldade, possuo um controller base onde o mesmo é herdado por mais outros três controllers base que realizam a sobrecarga e assim consigo realizar todas as funções necessárias no meu sistema.
Porém ao tentar aplicar a injenção de dependencia as classes filhas pedem para que eu passe o objeto construtor, então gostaria de saber como lidar com isso.

Estou usando o unity para fazer a injeção de dependencias.

Abaixo segue o código da controller pai:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public string[] includes = null;

    private readonly IFiltroServico servico;
    public BaseController(IFiltroServico _servico)
    {
        servico = _servico;
    }
}
```

Contoller filha, aqui é gerado o erro pois é necessário passar o IFiltroService devido o construtor da classe pai:

```
public abstract class BaseController<R> : BaseController
        where R : class
    {
 //services da controller;
    }
```

***Quero saber qual a melhor forma de fazer isso e como passar o construtor a partir daqui***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você herda uma classe que tem um construtor com parametros é necessário passar isso para a `base` dele, ou seja, você precisa passar o `IFiltroServico` no `base`

```
public abstract class BaseController<R> : BaseController
        where R : class
{
    public BaseController(IFiltroServico servico)
        :base(servico)
    {

    }
}
```

obs: o *underline* antes do nome da variavel é uma convenção para indicar que as variaveis são privadas, no caso ele "deveria" estar na propridade privada, uma vez que o `IFiltroServico` passado como parametro no construtor só está naquele escopo.

**EDIT**

Segue um exemplo que costumo usar quando uso o padrão `Repository`

```
public abstract class CrudRepository<TEntity, TKey> : ICrudRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext _context;
    public CrudRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //Codigo aqui
} 

public class UsuarioRepository : CrudRepository<Usuario, int>
{
    public UsuarioRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
     { }       
}
```

Comment: Ah sim entendi, eu até havia começado a passar o construtor para as classes filhas, porém ainda me resta uma dúvida além das quais já me sanou. Para a realização da Injeção de Dependência isso seria uma boa prática, no caso passar o construtor para as classes filhas?

Comment: Eu não havia visto ainda essa abordagem em `Controllers`, porém utilizo ela quando desenvolvo com padrão `repository` e `service`, no caso da repository, eu costumo criar uma classe generica que injeta o `Context`, logo preciso passar esse `Context` nas classes que herdam ela.

Comment: Entendo, esse padrão de controller também é um pouco novo para mim, porém gostei muito de como trabalhar com ele. Mas em relação a injeção de dependência pelo que vi vou usar um protected readonly na classe pai e chamar somente o construtor nas filhas. Isso até onde vi resolve meu problema e ainda é uma boa prática. Valeu

Comment: Sim, Sim, é assim mesmo, como disse, quando a classe pai tem um construtor parametrizado, deve ser passado na `base` das classes filhas.

Comment: Caso a resposta tenha resolvido seu problema, não esquece de dar OK, para que a pergunta seja finalizada.

Comment: Beleza valeu, vou fechar o tópico aqui valeu man.

Answer (score 1):

Só para complementar a resposta, após algumas pesquisas e dá resposta do manolo acima resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma:

Ao realizar a instancia do IFiltro eu o crio como protected e readonly, isso na base controller pai, segue abaixo:

```
 public class BaseController : ApiController
    {
        public string[] includes = null;
        protected readonly IFiltroServico _servico;
        public BaseController(IFiltroServico servico)
        {
            _servico = servico;
        }
    }
```

Nas classes filhas, basta seguir o exemplo do construtor da resposta acima.

Answer (score 1):

Em injeção de dependência, é possível você injetar um construtor.

Ex:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbGerenciador, DbGerenciador>(new InjectionConstructor(Provedor.PostgreSql, _conexaoString));
```

Comment: Interessante, você teria algum artigo mostrando mais do uso do D.I assim?